# How do I make a Firefox 57 addon that opens a link when left-clicked?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

This may sound dumb, but I want to make a link open in a new tab whenever the icon in the toolbar is left-clicked. I've never made a Firefox addon before, and I'm pretty clueless on how you'd go about doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need browserAction in manifest.json, tabs.create and browserAction.onClicked.

Inside manifest.json:

```
"browser_action": {
  "browser_style": true,
  "default_icon": {
    "32": "icons/icon-32.png"
  }
}
```

Inside background.js:

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    browser.tabs.create({url: "https://google.com"}); // 
    // or
    browser.tabs.duplicate({tabId: tab.id}); // duplicate current tab, same as doing browser.tabs.create({url: tab.url}); but better (navigation history is kept)
});
```

Don't forget to ask for the "tabs" or "activeTab" permission in manifest.json.

```
"permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab"]
```

And don't forget to register background.js

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```